# What are good statically-typed alternatives to PyTezos?

Tags: tezos-client

What are some good statically-typed Tezos client libraries (alternatives to PyTezos)?
I'm pretty language agnostic as I'm starting a new project.

I know about [TezEdge](https://github.com/tezedge/tezedge) (Rust), [tezos_dart](https://github.com/Tezsure/tezos_dart) (Dart), [Taquito](https://tezostaquito.io/) (TypeScript), and I guess `tezos_client` itself must be using an OCaml library somewhere (don't know where though).
I intend to write a few scripts to play with arbitrage*, DeFi concepts, etc.
I'm not interested in running a full node - I just want programmatic access to account generation, transfers, contract origination, and contract calls on testnets and mainnet.

Thanks!

*As a learning experience - I've noticed Tezos already has efficient arbitrage bots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of good libraries for Tezos that can be found on [Tezos Developer Portal](https://tezos.com/developer-portal).

As a C# dev I use the [Netezos](https://netezos.dev), Tezos SDK for .NET.

Comment: is there possibility of writing smart contract using netezos? if yes then kindly share any example

Answer (score 1):

An option not yet mentioned is the [morley-client](https://gitlab.com/morley-framework/morley/-/tree/master/code/morley-client) library for Haskell devs, which is part of the larger [morley](https://gitlab.com/morley-framework/morley) framework.

Its executable currently does not provide many options, but the library has a much wider coverage and it's what the network tests in [cleveland](https://gitlab.com/morley-framework/morley/-/tree/master/code/cleveland) are based upon.

You can find a better description of the main `morley` tools in the [dedicated wiki page](https://wiki.tezosagora.org/learn/smartcontracts/morley-framework), which is another place to find more info for Tezos development.

Comment: I haven't used Haskell since grad school, and I miss its elegance. This is def a strong contender ❤️